# Missing Toolbars items with CKEditor in WebPack Encore

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, symfony4, ckeditor4.x, webpack-encore

I have an Symfony form with CKEditor (installed with composer ("friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle": "^2.2")) and configure it with my custom toolbar.

It's fully worked but i'm trying to switch everything to WebpackEncore, it's actually works but I have an weird problem.

My fos-ckeditor.yml totally works before WebpackEncore

```
# Read the documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/index.html

twig:
    form_themes:
        - '@FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig'

fos_ck_editor:
    input_sync: true
    default_config: main_config
    configs:
        main_config:
            toolbar: "article_toolbar"
    toolbars:
        configs:
            article_toolbar: [ "@document", "@clipboard", "@editing", "@tools", "/", "@basicstyles", "@paragraph", "@links", "@insert", "/", "@styles", "@colors" ]
        items:
            document: [ 'Source', '-', 'Preview', '-' ]
            clipboard: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ]
            editing: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ]
            tools: [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks' ]
            basicstyles: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'CopyFormatting', 'RemoveFormat' ]
            paragraph: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-' ]
            links: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ]
            insert: [ 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar' ]
            styles: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ]
            colors: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ]
    #filebrowserUploadRoute: "my_route"
    #extraPlugins:           "wordcount"
```

[Result without WebpackEncore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDoLP.png)

My new config with WebpackEncore are the same with add this lines

```
fos_ck_editor:
    # ...
    base_path: "build/ckeditor"
    js_path:   "build/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"
    jquery_path: "build/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"
```

When I comment on these 3 previous config lines, the toolbar is displayed correctly but WebpackEncore are no longer used.
It seems that WebpackEncore builds the toolbar differently from ckeditor because output HTML doesn't have same structure...

Webpack.config.js

```
Encore
    // ...
        .copyFiles([
        {from: './node_modules/ckeditor4/', to: 'ckeditor/[path][name].[ext]', pattern: /\.(js|css)$/, includeSubdirectories: false},
        {from: './node_modules/ckeditor4/adapters', to: 'ckeditor/adapters/[path][name].[ext]'},
        {from: './node_modules/ckeditor4/lang', to: 'ckeditor/lang/[path][name].[ext]'},
        {from: './node_modules/ckeditor4/plugins', to: 'ckeditor/plugins/[path][name].[ext]'},
        {from: './node_modules/ckeditor4/skins', to: 'ckeditor/skins/[path][name].[ext]'}
    ])
    // ...
```

[Result with WebpackEncore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFhv2.png)

I followed all instructions in [Symfony's installation documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/installation.html#using-webpack-encore) and [Symfony's customize toolbar's documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/usage/toolbar.html)

I don't understand where the difference come from... Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

When you install ckeditor4, you install its standard version.
You can change the default behavior by modifying the file **fos_ckeditor.yaml**

For example, by default, you have the following conf (build/ckeditor/config.js) :
config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';

If you want to use these buttons, you can add in the **fos_ckeditor.yaml** file the option **removeButtons**

```
fos_ck_editor:
    configs:
        nameOfYourConfig:
            removeButtons: ~
```

You can also add plugins with **extraPlugins**:

```
fos_ck_editor:
    configs:
        nameOfYourConfig:
            removeButtons: ~
            extraPlugins: 'justify'
```

With the **justify** plugin, you will be able to use **JustifyLeft**, **JustifyCenter**, **JustifyRight**, **JustifyBlock** in your toolbar (not possible by default).

You will find below the list of options
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a conflict with the npm package & encore.

I had the same problem and I have found a dirty solution. It’s not a perfect solution but I have a complete toolbar with encore:

1. start removing the `npm` package

   ```
   yarn remove ckeditor
   ```

   or `ckeditor4`
2. Create your own `ckeditor`: [CK editor builder](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder)
3. After this copy paste your build to

   ```
   assets/ckeditor/build
   ```
4. in your webpack.js.config remove other ckeditors imports line and only use:

   ```
   {from: './assets/ckeditor/build', to: 'ckeditor/[path][name].[ext]'},
   ```

   and in your fos_ckeditor :

   ```
   fos_ck_editor:
       base_path: "build/ckeditor"
       js_path:   "build/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"
   ```

For me [it worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh8mG.png).

Comment: i have used a similar solution and I have written a comment in user's answer but it's not visible anymore.

My solution are  remove ckeditor with yarn, install asset with command `php bin/console ckeditor:install` and change webpack config with copyfiles entry (from public/bundle to build/ckeditor)

It's work but dirty,  thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue today and this happens because NPM installs the `standard-all` edition of ckeditor by default.
But FOSCKEditor download the `full` edition when using the command line.

So if you want to manage ckeditor with Webpack Encore, you also need to install the `full` edition using NPM:

```
npm install ckeditor/ckeditor4-releases#full/stable
```

See: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_package_managers.html#usage